# Vite Hot Reload and Laravel Homestead

Tags: laravel, windows, homestead, vite, laravel-9

I have a fresh Laravel 9 installation with Vite.

I use Laravel Homestead as a development environment (on top of a Windows 10 OS).

However, I cannot manage to make them work together: once I run `npm run dev`,  it always reloads the page every time I save my blade files. No hot reload, no state preserved. The page is refreshed as if I did `ctrl + R`.

I've tried different solutions on the web for similar cases, which involved updating `vite.config.js`, but none of them worked.

This is my `Homestead.yaml`

```yaml
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox
ssl: true

authorize: C:\Users\Luca\.ssh\id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - C:\Users\Luca\.ssh\id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:\Users\Luca\www\playground
      to: /home/vagrant/playground

sites:
    - map: playground.test
      to: /home/vagrant/playground/public
      php: "8.1"

databases:
    - playground

features:
    - mysql: true
    - mariadb: false
    - postgresql: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: true
```

then my `hosts` file

```
192.168.10.10   playground.test
```

and my `vite.config.js`

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite"
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin"

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    laravel({
      input: ["resources/css/app.css", "resources/js/app.js"],
      refresh: true,
    }),
  ],
  server: {
    host: "192.168.10.10",
    watch: {
      usePolling: true,
    },
  },
})
```

**P.S.:** I guess it is not related to it, but I use Blade & Tailwind. No Vue / React etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation:

> When your application is built using traditional server-side rendering
> with Blade, Vite can improve your development workflow by
> automatically refreshing the browser when you make changes to view
> files in your application. To get started, you can simply specify the
> refresh option as true.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#working-with-blade-and-routes

Comment: Already tried that (I'll edit the question), but that refreshes the page, so it is not HMR (which is instant). I start thinking that what I would like to happen is not possible because if I update my blade files, technically a new request to the PHP server has to be made in order to get the updates, so that HMR is not possible unless I add JS frameworks like Vue on top of Blade. What do you think about that?

Comment: When you work with php file (blade) only full realod is available

Comment: Yeah I should have expected that. Thanks